# cut -c won't work on my .sh file

Tags: shell, scripting, cut

I have tried the following commands

```
cut -c-11 ifshell.sh 

cat ifshell.sh | cut -c-11 ifshell.sh 

cat ifshell.sh | awk '{print $1} | cut -c-11 ifshell.sh
```

But every time I get the full contents of the .sh file. These commands work perfectly on .txt files. The primary goal is to extract the first 11 character of the script "#!/bin/bash" as checking if the file is really a bash bin script.

Comment: What's your goal? Are there more than 11 characters per line in ifshell.sh?

Comment: Well the primary goal is to extract the first 11 character of the script "#!/bin/bash" as checking if the file is really a bash bin script. And yes the first line contains 11 character -> "#!/bin/bash"

Comment: so - you're aware that cut operates on a line-by-line basis? If you only want the first line, you need to use something like `head -1 filename` or `sed -n 1p filename` before passing it to `cut`...

Comment: Thank you very much this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Or use `file ifshell.sh` and bypass the entire complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the standard ̀`file` command :

```
[PRD][]user@localhost:~ 17:21:30
$ head -n 1 setproxymkt.sh 
#!/bin/bash
[PRD][]user@localhost:~ 17:21:38
$ file setproxymkt.sh 
setproxymkt.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the following is better suited to what you are trying to accomplish:

```
# #// FILE could be a for-loop as well for example.
FILE="bash_scropt.sh" ;
if grep '#!/bin/bash' $FILE 1>/dev/null ; then
    printf "$FILE bash-script\n" ;
else
    printf "> $FILE -- NOT bash\n" ;
fi ;
```

You can also mix this with @netmonk suggestion where a grep on the head would be more concise eg:

```
FILE="bash_scropt.sh" ; if head -n 1 $FILE | grep '#!/bin/bash' 1>/dev/null ; then printf "$FILE bash-script\n" ; else printf "> $FILE -- NOT bash\n" ; fi
```

Comment: This is a great because you used the grep command, though I am a beginner still and can't figure out the meaning of ">/dev/null"

Comment: These are `redirections` - where the `1` (ie `... 1>/dev/null`) is the default level output & `2` related to errors. We're simply stating that we are not interested in the output of grep - rather in what the command returns - which is a return value of `0` from the command (not screen / output to console) in the cases of success / finding what we're after - otherwise any other return would indicate an error.